# Why not showing progressBar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I was trying to work with Progressbar in android studio. What I wanted was simply that when I will click on the button of the MainActivity it will intent to a new activity called 'Progress'.
My activities are here:

`MainActivity.java`:

[image: MainActivity.java]

and `Progress.java`:

[image: Progress.java]

My app runs, but not showing any progressbar motion. What should I do to show progressbar for 30 sec? I am not doing anything in the meantime. I just want to see a progressbar for 30 sec.

Comment: show some code please.

Comment: I have attached image in my question.Pls check @Caspain Caldion

Comment: Layout for progress bar

Comment: you show progress bar but value 100 is to small and you don't see is too fast

Comment: sorry I have not enough reputation to show more image.What can I do?

Comment: Here is the progressbar section @Caspain Caldion       :                                      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

Comment: I changed the value to 1000. still I can not see anything @Grzegorz

Comment: set visibility in xml to true

Comment: would you pls show me how to add this? @Caspain Caldion

Comment: default value for visibility is true no need set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 is too small for loop but this code do what you want :

```
//Set visible progres bar
findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Timer in your case 30 sek
        int timer = 30*1000;

        //create handler
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        //set handler delayed                
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 

        //Hidden progress bar
        findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //your toast
        Toast.makeText(this,"your msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //start new activity
        startActivity(your intent)
          }
        }, timer);
    }
```

Comment: Wow ! it works :) Can you pls tell me how can I show a toast message after the time is up and intent to a new activity? @Grzegorz

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's really helpful :) @Grzegorz

Answer (score 1):

mPrograssStatus is increasing to 100 in very short amount of time. You need to wait, for example try adding this to your code in loop while:

```
SystemClock.sleep(300);
```

value in brackets is amount of milliseconds that system will wait, in your case it is 300 to get 30 seconds. You also need to import library:

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
```

Comment: Thanks @Michał Tartanus for your reply. I have already got the solution :)